# How to use tickPositioner, to have different distance between lines of grid (Yaxis)?

Tags: highcharts

I want to change the distance between the grid lines (Y-axis) ..
They told me that I should use "tickPositioner" ...
But I have not figured out how ...

I have this code:

```
              yAxis: {

        reversed: true,
        categories: ['0','10','20','30','50','80','130','210','340','550','700'],                       
        labels: {
                    format: '{value} km',
                    enabled: true
                },
        title: {
                text: "profondita'"
                }

    },
    xAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 10,
        labels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
        gridLineWidth: 1,
        title: {
                      text: '<small><b>'+"Longitudine"+'</b></small>',
               }
    },
    zAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 10,
        labels: {
                    format: '{value} Lat',
                    enabled: true
                },
        title: {
                    text: "Latitude"
                }   
    },

    series: [{
        colorbypoint:
        { color: "#FF0000"},
        data: [
            // [X, Y, Z]
            [1, 1, 1],
            [1, 9, 2],
            [1, 1, 5],
            [2, 3, 2],
            [2, 6, 4],
            [4, 5, 7],
            [4, 2, 8],
            [7, 1, 3],
            [7, 1, 5],
            [8, 1, 5]
        ],

    }]
```

And I would have 50px between the first category and the second category (value between 0 and the value 10), have 70 px between the second category and the third category (between the value and the value 10 20) ..

If you can not show me a small example, you can tell me how I should proceed? I searched on StackOverflow but have not found anything useful

Comment: First can you show us a small example and live demo of what you want? something like jsfiddle...

Comment: I didn't found an example (or demo) that show what i want... On the Yaxis there are the lines of grid. For Each value of categories there is a line. But between the lines there is the same distance. I want different distance... I see that with "tinkPositioner" is possible (but with it the values categories on the Yaxis changed)..

Comment: Because the tickPositioner doesn't specify the distance between ticks, it specifies which ticks to show and which ones not to.

Comment: So what specify the distance betweeb ticks???

Comment: tickPixelInterval, but it's not applicable to categorized axes

Comment: Is incredible :( ... isn't there another way??

Answer (score 0):

You can use empty categories, but you will be able to set only multiples of single label distance.
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/j86jkfvj/69/

```
categories: ['0', '10', '20', '30', '40','50','60','70', '80','90','100','110','120', '130', '210', '340', '550', '700'],
tickPositions: [0,1,2,3,5,8,13],
```

Alternatively you could use other type of axis then categorized ('linear' - default one) as suggested in comments and adjust your data.